# How can I make a nicer-looking UISearchBar?

Tags: ios, uisearchbar

I like the delegate pattern and the way the UISearchbar works and acts, I just don't like how it looks. What's the shortest path to UI customization?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mean beyond what the UISearchBar reference documentation mentions?

From Apple's documentation:

> Customizing Appearance
>
> In iOS v5.0 and later, you can customize the appearance of search bars using the methods listed in “Customizing Appearance.” You can customize the appearance of all search bars using the appearance proxy ([UISearchBar appearance]), or just of a single bar.

And:

> Customizing Appearance
>
> backgroundImage
>
> – imageForSearchBarIcon:state:
>
> – setImage:forSearchBarIcon:state:
>
> – positionAdjustmentForSearchBarIcon:
>
> – setPositionAdjustment:forSearchBarIcon:
>
> inputAccessoryView
>
> scopeBarBackgroundImage
>
> – scopeBarButtonBackgroundImageForState:
>
> – setScopeBarButtonBackgroundImage:forState:
>
> – scopeBarButtonDividerImageForLeftSegmentState:rightSegmentState:
>
> – setScopeBarButtonDividerImage:forLeftSegmentState:rightSegmentState:
>
> – scopeBarButtonTitleTextAttributesForState:
>
> – setScopeBarButtonTitleTextAttributes:forState:
>
> – searchFieldBackgroundImageForState:
>
> – setSearchFieldBackgroundImage:forState:
>
> searchFieldBackgroundPositionAdjustment
>
> searchTextPositionAdjustment

Answer (score 0):

You can make your search Bar in a different way to make it better.
For that you have to take a textfield and take a image of search Bar as you want and set it on the textField and set the property of textfield.